# Linking 2 variables to one object

Tags: c#, class, jagged-arrays

Layers is a jagged array of Node, and each node as source[] and destination[] which represents array of Theta.

Question is, why when I change the code on the fourth line, the fifth line still prints '0' after I linked those objects?

```
theta t = new theta();
layers[1][i].source[j] = t;
layers[0][j].destination[i] = t;
layers[0][j].destination[i].weight = 5;
Console.WriteLine(layers[1][i].source[j].weight);

struct theta
{
    public double weight;
    public theta(double _weight) { weight = _weight; }
}

class node
{
    public theta[] source;
    public theta[] destination;
    public double activation;
    public double delta;

    public node() { }
    public node(double x) { activation = x; }
}
```

Sample on how the layers are filled:

```
node n = new node();
n.destination = new theta[numberOfNodesPerHiddenLayer+1];
n.source = new theta[numberOfNodesPerHiddenLayer+1];
layers[i][j] = n;
```

Comment: You should clarify how the `layers` array is filled.

Comment: Please post the entire outer/nested loops (if applicable) code snippet because it's unclear where indices i and j came from. Rgds,

Comment: change structure to class and everything will work. With the present use there is no point in having structure there

Comment: Layers are instantiated individually on each of its dimension. Here's a sample of code on how the layers (which is an array of node) is filled:

`node n = new node();`

`n.destination = new theta[numberOfNodesPerHiddenLayer+1];`

`n.source = new theta[numberOfNodesPerHiddenLayer+1];`
`layers[i][j] = n;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Theta is a STRUCT, not class. Structs are implicitly copied. When you are doing:

```
theta t = new theta();
layers[1][i].source[j] = t;
layers[0][j].destination[i] = t;
```

you end up with three copies of 't'. One original, one at index 1,i and one at index 0,j. Then, you assign 5 to only one of the copies. All others stay unmodified. This is how structs are different from class: they are assigned by value copying, not by-reference.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works perfectly! I thought `struct` was just another class but with limitations such as no functions/procedures for simplification sake. I should go read books more!  D:

Answer (score 0):

That is because `struct` is a *value-type* (as opposed to a *reference type*) and has value-type copy-semantics. See for example this post: [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c) for more information.

If you change the type of `theta` to `class` it will likely work the way you expect.